# mongodb .NET driver update nested array

Tags: .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to increase a value in a nested array accessing by index. To make sense, Client object contains a list of Order object. Order object contains int Stars. My goal is to increase Stars int by one like:

```
            await mongoContext.Clients.UpdateOneAsync(x => x.Id == model.PostId,
           Builders<Client>.Update.Inc(x => x.Orders.ElementAt(index).Stars, 1));
```

Code above gives me error message:
[image]
If I pass an exact number (not variable), it works fine:

```
            await mongoContext.Clients.UpdateOneAsync(x => x.Id == model.PostId,
           Builders<Client>.Update.Inc(x => x.Orders.ElementAt(0).Stars, 1));
```

I have also tried the simpler approach `x => x.Orders[index].Stars` (not through "ElementAt()") but it keeps failing.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: How do you define `index` in your code ?

Comment: its an int variable passed to through the controller as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, please check [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1246)

It is solved in driver versions later to 2.0.0 (2.6.0 is the current one).